# How to unpack (64-bit) unsigned long in 64-bit Perl?

Tags: perl, 64-bit, unpack

I'm trying to unpack an unsigned long value that is passed from a C program to a Perl script via SysV::IPC.

It is known that the value is correct (I made a test which sends the same value into two queues, one read by Perl and the second by the C application), and all predecessing values are read correctly (used `q` instead of `i!` to work with 64-bit integers).

It is also known that PHP had [something similar](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) in bugs (search for "unsigned long on 64 bit machines") (seems to be similar:
*[Pack / unpack a 64-bit int on 64-bit architecture in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265285/php-pack-unpack-64bit-int-on-64bit-architecture)*)

Arguments tested so far:

- ..Q ( = some value that is larger than expected)
- ..L   ( = 0)
- ..L!  ( = large value)
- ..l ( = 0)
- ..l! ( = large value)
- ..lN! ( = 0)
- ..N, ..N! ( = 0)

`use bigint; use bignum;` -- no effect.

Details:

- `sizeof(unsigned long)` = 8;
- `Data::Dumper->new([$thatstring])->Useqq(1)->Dump();` a lot of null bytes along some meaningful..
- byteorder='12345678';

Solution:
 - `x4Q` with padding four bytes.

Comment: Show output of `Data::Dumper->new($string)->Useqq(1)->Dump` on your packed string and what number you are expecting.  And maybe output of perl -V:byteorder

Comment: sorry, I mean output of `print Data::Dumper...`

Comment: @ysth, VAR1 = "\210\23\0\0\0\0\0\0\210\23\0\0\0\0\0\0\177\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\177\0\0\1\0\0\0\0W\273\@\37\0\0\0\0}^\330u\0\0\0\0\264\13\340u\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\16T\223M\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"; - wow, too much \0's, checking. Maybe `my $string` declaration doesn't fits return type somewhere.

Comment: Have your tried just unpacking a scalar constant coded in the script? Once you get that working, try the pipe...

Comment: @drewk, nope, I just can run all three programs simultaneously, (Perl version currently does no work unless I can get away this unpack trouble) and it can be restarted quickly.. not a time for unit test :)

Comment: What is "predecessing values"? Do you mean "preceding values"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple: added `x4Q` to skip four bytes before actual value; need to more visually think of padding/alignment..

Answer (score 3):

Unpacking using `Q` in [the template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#pack) works out of the box if you have 64-bit Perl:

```
The TEMPLATE is a sequence of characters that give the order
and type of values, as follows:

 ...

 q   A signed quad (64-bit) value.
 Q   An unsigned quad value.
       (Quads are available only if your system supports 64-bit
        integer values _and_ if Perl has been compiled to support those.
        Causes a fatal error otherwise.)
```

For a more robust solution, unpack the value into an 8-byte string and use the [`Math::Int64`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3a%3aInt64) module to convert it to an integer:

```
use Math::Int64 qw( :native_if_available int64 );

...

$string_value = unpack("A8", $longint_from_the_C_program);

# one of these two functions will work, depending on your system's endian-ness
$int_value = Math::Int64::native_to_int64($string_value);
$int_value = Math::Int64::net_to_int64($string_value);
```

Comment: Neither works correctly; source value = 563026057, same unpacked in secondary C app, native_to_int64 = 2418178501610831872, net_to_int64 = 2300088097