# How to unpack() this structure with PHP?

Tags: php, binary, unpack

How to unpack() the first structure in [this list](http://www.par2.net/par2spec.php#i__134603784_354)?

I want the second field as integer (or to say better as float since PHP doesn't support 64bit int)

Comment: PHP supports 64-bit integers. Just `unpack` doesn't. Read out two 32-bit values an combine them. (Can't test, no legacy installation handy.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: pack / unpack 64bit int on 64bit architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265285/php-pack-unpack-64bit-int-on-64bit-architecture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mario, I solved it like this:

```
$a = unpack("i", $this->read(4));
$b = unpack("i", $this->read(4));
$packet['file_length'] = $a[1] + $b[1] * 0x100000000;
```

Where `$this->read()` is a wrapper for:

```
mb_substr($data, $offset, $length, '8bit');
```

Comment: Interesting, that this should work. "Combining two 32bit" does not mean to just add them: `($a[1] << 32) + $b[1]`. You must shift the upper 32 bits 32 bits to the left, to make space for the lower 32bits.

Comment: Your are right, however it doesn't work as you propose. I tried to convert the following data to integer (from hex editor): 62 EA 9F 33 01 00 00 00 That should be 5.161.085.538 (~5gb), but it spits out int(866118243). The Par2 doc says all integers are little endian (which means I must use 'V' in unpack, though 'I' results in same data...). Any idea?.

Comment: Got it finally: `$packet['file_length'] = $a[1] + $b[1] * 0x100000000;`

Comment: This will only work until you hit the precision of a float... you will then lose the least significant bits. If I'm not mistaken, you have significant 52 bits in an IEEE 64-bit floating point value, which is hopefully enough for your purposes :-)